# Load audio files from android directory in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to develop an app in Unity. This basic app is a cube(audio source) and a camera in a room.

I need to load audio files (preferably mp3) from android directory when i touch this cube.

Hoy can i do that?

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

check this link : https://answers.unity.com/questions/517837/how-to-play-mp3-mp4-files-on-the-local-disk.html

Inf fact, you need plugin to load MP3 so you can use OGG file.